# Creating instances of global temporary table

Tags: oracle, plsql, temp-tables

I created a GTT at schema level

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE schema1.gtt1
    (
    col1 type1,
    col2 type2,
    ...
    )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE  ROWS;
```

Now I can reference the table from within a PLSQL block/procedure/function very easily:

```
INSERT INTO schema1.gtt1
   select col1, col2, ... from ...;
```

but what if in the same PLSQL block I want to insert values in another global temporary table (GTT) with the same structure as the one I created?

Do I have to create another GTT, and give it another name even if it has the very same structure (I think it would be awkward)? or can I somehow create multiple instances of a GTT?

Don't know if it's relevant but I'll be joining the GTT's with other tables, within the same PLSQL block.

Comment: Each session has its own segregated data in the GTT, but only in once instance of it. Are you sure you actually want GTTs at all though, rather than collections? Particularly if you need multiple instances (which you can do with multiple variables of the same collection table type) which only exist within the PL/SQL block?

Comment: Also please note that in 12c, that the statistics on a GTT are session private too.

Comment: @Alex Poole, thanks for your reply,I think I've been having a hard time trying to understand why do you have to declare objects, and tables based on those objects outside plsql. My purpose was creating a function that returned some data in the most straight forward way possible (defining and creating whatever I need within the same plsql function, creating subquerys without the need of `INTO`) I somehow feel that PLSQL has its way of overcomplicating things so I was trying to avoid collections at all. I guess using collections would be the appropiate path to follow in PLSQL. So I'll use them.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 tables, A and B with same structure. (GTT but accessed from same session so we can ignore this) 
Your question do I have to insert in both at runtime or can I use only one?

This is a question that only you can answer based on the meaning of what you insert and your need to differentiate the records. 
If you need to make the difference between these 2 record sets (what you insert in A and what in B) but you have no key to make this distinction than you would need to: add a new column in structure like "source" or insert into different tables.

There is no "multiple instances" concept of GTT within session so this won't do the trick.